# Randomly drop elements from pandas series, based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with ~150 million float elements. I am trying to randomly drop a 50% of all elements whose value lie between a specific range (say, between -0.1 and 0.1).

Normally I would (1) create a dataframe from the series; (2) add a column with random numbers; (3) drop those rows that satisfy the first condition (between -0.1 and 0.1) and whose random number is in the lower 20th percentile. However, doing this saturates my PCs memory and won't work, so I am trying to find a way to do this directly from the series without much manipulation.

For example, I have something like this (but much bigger in reality):

```
0            0.05
1            -0.05
2            0.03
3            0.12
4            0.03
5            -0.2
6            -0.05
7            0.13
8            -0.2
9            0
Length: 10, dtype: float64
```

And I am trying to drop randomly the 50% of all values between -0.1 and 0.1, which would give an output like this:

```
0            0.05
3            0.12
4            0.03
5            -0.2
6            -0.05
7            0.13
8            -0.2
```

Is there any way to do this directly from the series and without much manipulation?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Dropping == replace by `NaN` value

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to drop all the elements with a specific value. I am trying to randomly drop elements inside (-0.1, 0.1), so some elements with a value might remain while other identical elements might be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way manipulating only the indexes:

```
m = ((df > -.1) & (df < .1))
idx = df.loc[~m].index.union(df.loc[m].sample(frac=.5).index)
df[idx]
```

Output:

```
0    0.05
1   -0.05
2    0.03
3    0.12
5   -0.20
7    0.13
8   -0.20
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Details: Create a boolean series where m meets your conditions of rows to be sampled from and dropped.  Union the invert of the boolean series with a sample of 50% of the Trues and use that new series to boolean index the original series.